# PLSQL - 2 FOR loops on nested tables

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, nested-table

PLSQL - 2 FOR loops on nested tables, one after the other, the second loop isn't performed while the nested table of the first loop is empty.
Follow is the code snippet:

```
type prod_seq_array is table of wiz_customer_hp_product.product_seq%type;
c_prod_add_arr    prod_seq_array := prod_seq_array ();
c_prod_drop_arr   prod_seq_array := prod_seq_array (1234,5678);
      FOR i IN c_prod_add_arr.FIRST .. c_prod_add_arr.LAST LOOP
      mydebug2.debug_out(fp,'shira2 ' ||wo_prod_rec_1.product_seq);
         if v_prod_seq = c_prod_add_arr(i) then
            v_status := 'C';
            ins_hp_prod_svc;
            v_drop_wo_date := v_add_date;
            exit;
         end if;
      END LOOP;
      FOR i IN c_prod_drop_arr.FIRST .. c_prod_drop_arr.LAST LOOP
         if v_prod_seq = c_prod_drop_arr(i) then
            v_status := 'C';
            del_hp_prod_svc_hist ;
            v_drop_wo_date := v_drop_date;
            exit;
         end if;
      END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that FOR loop on empty nested table will throw exception so I added the following condition before each FOR loop

```
if c_prod_add_arr.count > 0 
  FOR i IN c_prod_add_arr.FIRST .. c_prod_add_arr.LAST LOOP
     if v_prod_seq = c_prod_add_arr(i) then
        v_status := 'C';
        ins_hp_prod_svc;
        v_drop_wo_date := v_add_date;
        exit;
     end if;
  END LOOP;
end if;
```